# Where can I get a functional Wi-Fi Direct demo Android Application Project for ADT?

Tags: android, adt, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I've seen references to a Wi-Fi Direct demo app on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) but I don't know how to locate and/or import it.  Most of the Android tutorials are straight-forward and I can download and add the project as existing code (for example [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)), but I'm not having any luck with Wi-Fi Direct.

This doesn't necessarily have to be the stock Wi-Fi Direct demo (assuming one exists).  I just want something I can pull into ADT so I have some example source code.  (I'm aware there are code snippets on the Wi-Fi Direct page I linked but I'm looking for a known-functional project, not pieces.)

For reference I'm running Android Developer Tools Build: v21.1.0-569685 and I have two phones running Android version 4.2.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use  sdk manager to download samples for any api above 14 . In that you shall find a wifidirectdemo sample app which shall help you get aquainted with the basic of wifi direct in android

Comment: Thanks.  I eventually figured this out on my own.  My confusion was that I didn't realize the ADT GUI (eclipse.exe) and the SDK Manager (SDK Manager.exe) were two separate applications.  I thought I could launch the SDK Manager via ADT, which isn't the case (or at least not that I could find).  I'm new at Android development and it's a newbie problem.


I'll also point out that for Windows users, you may not be able to launch SDK Manager.exe directly due to Java path issues.  I was able to launch it successfully via the sdk/tools/android.bat script.


Hope that helps somebody else!

Answer (score 10):

Just for the sake of up to date information, for API level 19 and 20, these demos have been moved to the legacy directory :

`installationPath\samples\android-19\legacy\WiFiDirectDemo`

Comment: If this is legacy, is there newer better way to handle wifi direct?

Comment: up is there new solutions ?

Comment: Well, the demo is still available.

Answer (score 5):

It would be at
installation path\samples\android-17\WiFiDirectDemo

Answer (score 0):

For anyone bumps into this need, this is a direct link for the WiFiDirectDemo app source.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo